# PHP database tables query help request - String variables

Tags: php, string

Currently I am creating a news section for a website.

I have created it so that the news type is separated by a string E.g. category = ,2,4,6,

I don't normally use strings a whole lot, and my initial thought was to do something like this:

```
$query_listelements = "SELECT * FROM newsitems WHERE released = 1 AND (category = 2  OR category = 4 OR category = 6) ORDER BY date_rel DESC";
```

Clearly this won't work as I need to isolate / expand the string. so it needs to be something like:

```
$query_listelements = "SELECT * FROM newsitems WHERE released = 1 AND (category = strval(",2,")  OR category = strval(",4,") OR category = strval(",6,")) ORDER BY date_rel DESC";
```

I don't think the above is the right way to go out things either.

Any thoughts would be really valued!

Comment: Don't go this route. normalize your database with a news_category table, otherwise it will cause you so much pain in the future

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your feedback. I actually think having the category setup this way will actually be okay if I can setup the category this way will be fine. If I can figure out a way to do this. The actual categories won't be changing/dynamic, so future-proofing it should not be a trouble.

Comment: This isn't simply about future proofing so that you can add new categories... it's about the ease of searching on categories. A news_category table makes it a lot easier to search, and cn also be indexed for performance; while a comma-separated column of category ids requires a more complex query, and any index on the column can't be used by the SQL engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like below, sounds better to me.

```
$category= array ( 2, 4, 6);
$category = implode(',', $category); //Now it is a string like '2,4,6'
$query_listelements = "SELECT * FROM newsitems WHERE released = 1 AND (category IN ($category)) ORDER BY date_rel DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, this is very close to the solution that I am after, though unfortunately I cannot seem to get the code to behave in a way. I get an 'unexpected T_VARIABLE' error.

Comment: add semicolon ";" after second line. Editing my answer now.